# Running a Visual Studio 2015 C++ Executable Without Installing the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

**Short Version:**  Is it possible to run an executable compiled with Visual Studio 2015 without installing the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages, and instead copying the runtime DLLs into the same folder as your executable?

**Long Version...**

Since the mid 1990s I have written small programs using Visual C++ and then later Visual Studio.  Up until Visual Studio 2013 I have always been able to run these programs on any Windows host as long I put msvcpXXX.dll and msvcrXXX.dll in the same directory.  I have never needed to install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages.

Now with Visual Studio 2015 this appears to no longer work.  First there is no msvcrXXX.dll.  So I copied msvcp140.dll and three other DLLs I found in the Visual Studio folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT (concrt140.dll, vccorlib140.dll, vcruntime140.dll).  Still doesn't run.

Looking at the depends.exe makes me think there are a lot of dependencies that are not resolved in these DLLs.  I confess I got a little overwhelmed and didn't keep digging on my own to figure out every DLL I need to have to satisfy the dependencies.  But it started feeling very hacky, as many of them were installed under C:\Windows and not present in my Visual Studio redistributable folders.

Anyway, can anyone help?

Comment: What about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31811597/3962537)? Or perhaps link statically to the runtime? Personally I just use the redistributable, it's a lot less hassle.

Comment: Static linking worked on Windows 10 and 2012 hosts.  But on my Windows 2008 hosts it wouldn't start due to api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing.  It looks like the question you linked to may answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was surprisingly not closed as a duplicate.  And I hate leaving open questions unanswered.  So I'll answer it myself by saying that codestation's comment links to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601941/msvc-2015-universal-crt-for-app-local-deployment) which links to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) which describes how to do this in the section that starts with bold red text.

You shouldn't upvote this.  Upvote the answer in the linked question.

Comment: Fixed that for you. :-)